# How to execute RoboSpice requests synchronously?

Tags: robospice

How to execure RoboSpice requests synchronously? Is it possible? I would like to use RoboSpice in IntentService.

Edit:

From time to time comes the need to execute something synchronously e.g. in service. In my recent project I have to queue some different types of requests and I wanted to use IntentService with RoboSpice. In my case when I'm executing different requests I need to wait for results from `request1` then pass data from it to `request2` and execute it.

I want to have some kind of batch request queue. Lets say we have two types of request: `request1` and `request2`. `request2` needs data fetched by `request1`:

1. execute `request1`
2. wait
3. get data fetched by `request1` and pass to `request2`
4. execute `request2`
5. wait
6. goto 1.

I wanted to use IntentService (queue) but it dies after starting requests because of async.

In my opinion using listeners or CountDownLatch isn't the best way.

Comment: I have the same problem, working on it too :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As proposed by Riccardo Ciovatti [on the RoboSpice mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/robospice/gSg_Wq24eto/5rC15SBO5IsJ), a direct answer to your question is :

```
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

final YourRequest request = new YourRequest();
spiceManager.execute(request, new RequestListener<YourResponse>() {

    @Override
    public void onRequestFailure(SpiceException spiceException) {
        latch.countDown();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestSuccess(YourResponse response) {
        latch.countDown();
    }
});

latch.await();
```

But this isn't a good idiom to use unless it's being executed on a background thread. Asynchronous processing is an essential feature of RoboSpice; it keeps the UI thread free.

Comment: The new question is not about a sync request but how to chain them. In that case, execute the second request from the listener of the first.

Comment: @Snicolas I've been searching for a simple way to execute a RoboSpice request synchronously and have reluctantly settled on this pattern. Everywhere I see it discussed you disregard it as a valid requirement due to blocking the UI thread, but what if you're not executing it from the UI thread, in my case I'd like to do it in the `performFiltering` method of a `Filter`. This method is executed from a worker thread so there's no need to offload execution to the service. Seems like unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @darnmason, your comment is a little confusing to me. If you want to execute a request synchronously, just execute it's getDataFromNetwork method. In the end of your comment, you would like not to use a service to perform your request, but this is the essence of RS. If you want to chain the requests, then Ricardo's method is fine. But I agree, RS could provide an alternative approach where you get a Future of the result but it would be hard to get the fine-grained semantics that listener have with their different callbacks. Please submit a Github issue if you have a clear API to reach for RS.

Answer (score 1):

Using RoboSpice in IntentService. Solved the problem with help of CountDownLatch. Let's say we have 2 different SpiceManagers and some syncMethods to execute in sequence in the IntentService.

**Globals**:

```
private final SpiceManager aSpiceManager =
       new SpiceManager(ASpiceService.class);
private final SpiceManager bSpiceManager =
       new SpiceManager(BSpiceService.class);

private CountDownLatch handleIntentLatch;
```

**onHandleIntent**: Before we execute syncMethodA - we init our CountDownLatch with 1. After executing syncMethodA we await() for countDown() on our latch. When later some method will call countDown() on our latch at least once - method onHandleIntent will continue it's execution and finish which will trigger IntentService onDestroy() callback.

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    handleIntentLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    syncMethodA();

    try {
        handleIntentLatch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**syncMethodA()**:
Suppose we need to launch some sync methods in sequence (syncMethodA which callback executes syncMethodB etc).

```
private void syncMethodA() {
    SpiceRequest requestA = new SpiceRequest();

    if (!aSpiceManager.isStarted()) {
        LogUtils.LOGD(TAG, "starting aSpiceManager");
        aSpiceManager.start(getApplicationContext());
    }

    aSpiceManager.execute(requestA , new RequestListener<ResponseA>() {
        @Override
        public void onRequestSuccess(final ResponseA responseA) {
            // SOME LOGIC

            syncMethodB();

            // SOME LOGIC

        @Override
        public void onRequestFailure(SpiceException spiceException) {
            handleIntentLatch.countDown();
            // SOME LOGIC
        }
    });
}
```

syncMethodB, syncMethodC etc are the same - in **onRequestSuccess** we start next syncMethodX. In on **onRequestFailure** we countDown() our latch (handleIntentLatch).

**Very important!!!** 
In last syncMethodX in sequence (after which completion we want onHandleIntent method to continue it's execution and finish which will result IntentService to stop) - we countDown() our latch in **onRequestSuccess** **ALSO**.

**onDestroy**: here we stop our SpinceManagers.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    LogUtils.LOGD(TAG, "onDestroy");
    shutDownSpiceManagers();
}
```

**shutDownSpiceManagers**:

```
private void shutDownSpiceManagers() {
    if (aSpiceManager.isStarted()) {
        LogUtils.LOGD(TAG, "stopping aSpiceManager");
        aSpiceManager.shouldStop();
    }
    if (bSpiceManager.isStarted()) {
        LogUtils.LOGD(TAG, "stopping bSpiceManager");
        bSpiceManager.shouldStop();
     }
}
```

All should be OK now: no leaked Context, SpiceManagers will be killed in onDestroy **AND ONLY AFTER** callbacks are resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want exactly synchronous execution, but only want requests to be executed sequentially in some order, you may write your own simple class which will just execute request B when request A succeeded or failed. Like that: https://github.com/Deepscorn/Shared/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/gamelift/shared/request/base/RequestSequenceExecutor.java.
So, code will look like:

```
sequenceExecutor.setRequest(new FirstRequest());
sequenceExecutor.setOnSuccessListener(FirstRequest.class, new OnSuccessListener {
   public void onSuccess() {
     sequenceExecutor.setRequest(new SecondRequest());
   }
};

sequenceExecutor.setOnFaulListener(FirstRequest.class, new OnFailListener {
   public void onFail() {
     sequenceExecutor.setRequest(new OnFirstFailRequest());
   }
};

sequenceExecutor.setOnSuccessListener(SecondRequest.class, new OnSuccessListener {
   public void onSuccess() {
     notifyDone();
     return;
   }
};

sequenceExecutor.setDefaultOnFailListener(new OnFailListener {
   public void onFail(Exception e) {
     notifyDone();
     log(e);
     return;
   }
};
sequenceExecutor.execute() //starts execution
```